# Cakephp's JS helper

Tags: cakephp

Forgive this question for being a little subjective but if you're just looking at inserting html into the DOM/showing/hiding etc do I have to use the JS helper or can I write normal jQuery and include it in the views head?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write normal JS, either include a JS file or use script tags. You can place it either in the view or the layout. Cake is just there if you need it. I like to do things the "cake" way, but I have never used the JS helper.